# openFrameworks: Sounds repeat too fast it's a glitch--how to slow down?

Tags: audio, openframeworks

I'm trying to create a simple musical instrument using OF. Basically, it's a bunch of different balls bouncing around the screen. Each ball represents a musical note. If any two balls come close enough, two notes (of those balls) will be played.

I've managed to play the sounds. But they repeat themselves too fast it's sound more like a glitch. When the balls separate, that's when the sounds are properly played.

I wonder if there is anyway to slow down the repetition?

Comment: Some relevant fragment of your source code might help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

It makes total sense because you check for distance between balls multiple times per second and when the distance is past a threshold, you trigger a sound at the same rate (multiple tims per second).

You probably want something like:

```
in update loop:
for each ball
  if distance to other ball < threshold distance
    if the collision sound isn't already playing/hasn't finished
       play collision sound
```

Basically, when a collision is detected you want to trigger the sound once, not multiple times.